# Buddhist-themed science fiction short story from the point of view of large bird viewing the planet from the sky

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago (55!), I read a short story that I thought was Buddhist-inspired. It was about a shared awareness, communal-minded world, in which, all living beings were linked into one awareness.  Animal/plant/all life.  It is written from the perspective of one being, from the point of view of a large bird that soars above the world-mind and observes the descent and landing of a human spaceship.

What makes this Buddhist is the deep acceptance of the bird as it observes the humans' unwitting destruction of the sentient biome. There is no separation of the bird from its world, but there exists a separate will, a curiosity about the new object from the sky.  The view is complete compassion for the interlopers, down to the self-sacrifice of the bird, who allows itself to be captured so as to be nearer the specimen-gathering Earthmen.

The planet of origin of the spaceship is kept from the reader until the end, when the bird listens in to their ignorant conversations.  In the end the bird accepts/wills that he submits to being dissected and studied by the men.

Comment: Is there an explicit reference to Buddhism in the story, or is that just your interpretation?

Comment: Do you happen to remember anything about the book  the story was in?

Comment: There was no explicit reference to Buddhism, just a deep non-ego viewpoint.  The bird, acting as the story-teller was inseparable from the world and its inhabitants, plant animal and even non=sentient earth.  I am sorry

Comment: here was no explicit reference to Buddhism, just a deep non-ego viewpoint.  The bird, acting as the center of interest for the omniscient narrator was inseparable from the world and its inhabitants, plant and animal, delegated to investigate the strange arrival, but completely part of a planet-wide consciousness.  Not Buddhist canon, but a good embodiment of the view.

Comment: I don't remember which book it appeared in, but I think it was an anthology.

Comment: Is "Years ago (55!)" intended to convey "Years ago (I'm 55!)"? Or perhaps "About 55 years ago"? Or even "Years ago, around '55"?

Comment: I meant 55 years ago, (Yikes!!!), when I was 17 years old.